# Alert window in 'application as agent' not given focus

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, alert

**UPDATE:** My application is runing as agent, I found when I turn that off, the alert window is given focus normally. Any ideas how to solve that?

I am showing an alert window first time the application is ran in AppController's awakeFromNib. When I run it in Xcode, it's runs as a key window, but when I build the app, it's not given focus. Why? How can I give it focus?

**AppController.m**

```
NSInteger kbSetup = NSRunAlertPanel(kbLetsStart, kbLetsStartDscr, @"OK", @"Maybe Later", nil);
kbSetup == 1 ? [self showPreferencesPanel:nil] : [NSApp performSelector:@selector(terminate:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

Even if I create an instance of NSAlert, and then do `[[alert window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]` , it's still not key...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, the solution is calling `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];` before opening alert. doh.